# Design guidelines proportional pitched fonts

Tags: typography, design-principles, font-design

I searched the internet and a big local bookstore for a good resource on designing proportional pitched fonts.

I know there is no fixed rule-book on how the width of a specific glyph or ligature is determined, but are there general rules of thumb or a guideline where to start from?

Which letter does one typically start from? Are there approximations of relationship between different glyphs, e.g. "m" and "n" and "r" or something like that?

Any tips, book recommendations will help. Thank you guys.

Comment: This may also be of interest: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2588/what-characters-are-good-to-start-with-when-designing-a-typeface/39578#39578

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What characters are good to start with when designing a typeface?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2588/what-characters-are-good-to-start-with-when-designing-a-typeface)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommended *Designing Type* by Karen Cheng. She goes through various relationships between letters with regards to width but also stroke thickness variations and vertical proportions depending on type families, as well as side bearings, kerning, etc. Typically, the uppercase M will be the wider letter in terms of proportions. We use her book for a typographic design class where I teach.

She advises to start setting the proportions and personality of your font by starting with **a, e, g, n and o.** Then you can work on a word often used by type designers "**hamburgefontsiv**". From this word you can build most of the other letters.